# Browser automation downloading to default location

Tags: ruby, watir

I have browser automation using Watir and it uses chrome to drive it. the downloads needs to be in my app sub folder. But i am not able to change it as it downloads to the windows download folders

```js
download_dir = "#{Dir.pwd}/downloads".tr('/', '\\')
Dir.mkdir download_dir unless Dir.exist ? download_dir
args = % w(--disable - infobars)
prefs = {
  download: {
    prompt_for_download: false,
    download_directory: download_dir
  }
}
ie = Watir::Browser.new(: chrome, options: {
  args: args
}, prefs: prefs)
```

Answer (score 0):

They have made some mistake in the recent selenium, that's what it's not working. I filed a bug here

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7917

So please install selenium-webdriver 3.142.6, it's working fine.

Comment: it keeps installing a higher version. How can i use that version
C:\ProgramData\TradingTools\automation>gem list selenium-webdriver

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)

C:\ProgramData\TradingTools\automation>gem install selenium-webdriver 3.142.6
Successfully installed selenium-webdriver-3.142.7
Parsing documentation for selenium-webdriver-3.142.7
Done installing documentation for selenium-webdriver after 1 seconds
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '3.142.6' (>= 0) in any repository
1 gem installed

Comment: @junkone you have to provide the version while you are installing `gem install selenium-webdriver -v 3.142.6` or `gem install selenium-webdriver --version 3.142.6`

Comment: thanks. did extra google and fixed my version. But i still have the same problem with the 3.142.6 where the downloads goto the download folder
C:\ProgramData\TradingTools\automation>gem list selenium-webdriver

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

selenium-webdriver (3.142.6)

Comment: Hi, I know `tr` is the correct method, but can you use it in the same way I use here once and check it now? because that's the only change I see as of now. This is what I used in my file and it works for me `custom_download_dir = File.expand_path("../../../Output/Downloads/#{@scenario}/#{@testCase[0] + '_' + @testCase[1]}", __FILE__).gsub('/', '\\')`

Comment: nope. changing to gsub does not create any difference. Acually, my code creates the download folder but chrome does not target that folder. 
   download_dir = "#{Dir.pwd}/downloads".gsub('/', '\\')
Dir.mkdir download_dir unless Dir.exist? download_dir
args     = %w(--disable-infobars)
prefs    = { download: { prompt_for_download: false, default_directory: download_dir }}

       

  ie=Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, options: { args: args }, prefs: prefs)

Comment: @junkone, this bug has been verified by the Selenium team. In the short-term, you can workaround the issue by switching the pref keys to be `String` instead of `Symbol` - [see workaround in the issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7917#issuecomment-579271732).

Answer (score 0):

Changing a driver directly worked for me:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, options: { prefs: prefs })
browser.driver.download_path = downloads_path
```

where `downloads_path` represents the custom directory you want to set.